# Selenium Java code cannot catch textbox

Tags: java, html, selenium, authentication, business-intelligence

I'm not able to read this textbox to type in some text. The webpage is a login screen for Business Objects SAP tool.

Here's the HTML-

```
<div class="logon_table" >
<div id="userName" class="logon_input" >
<label class="logon_input_label" tabindex="-1" for="usernameTextEdit" > ... </label>
<input id="usernameTextEdit" class="inputTextBox logonTextBox" type="text" value="****" name="username" ></input>
</div>
**Same for passwordTextEdit
</div>
```

I tried the following but to no avail. Also, tried with `XPath` but not sure if I'm making a correct syntax to reach usernameTextEdit-

```
driver.findElement(By.id("usernameTextEdit")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("usernameTextEdit")).sendKeys("SomeUserName");
```

Comment: What happens? Did you get some Exception? It works for me

Comment: Exception thrown : org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"usernameTextEdit"}
Command duration or timeout: 30.06 seconds

Comment: Try it with this link: `http://walery.bitbucket.org/org.walery.stackoverflow.q19002075/` this was my test side that I copied from your question

Comment: Indeed works there, I wonder what's bad with my BO login page.

Comment: Probably the complete page hierarchy. Here's the complete hierarchy of the page - <div class="logonContainer"> <div class="logonIFrame"> <iframe id="infoView_home" ...> <html class="logon_body" ...> <div class="logon_body" > <div id=messageDiv" class="logon_message"> <div id="logonCredentails" > <form action=...> <div class="logon_table"> ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have iframe in this site. You have to switch there first.

This should work:

```
WebElement iframe = webDriver.findElement(By.id("infoView_home"));
webDriver.switchTo().frame(iframe);

webDriver.findElement(By.id("usernameTextEdit")).clear();
webDriver.findElement(By.id("usernameTextEdit")).sendKeys("SomeUserName");

webDriver.findElement(By.id("passwordTextEdit")).clear();
webDriver.findElement(By.id("passwordTextEdit")).sendKeys("Some Password");
```

Comment: Sorry for the error. Yes indeed a mistake. I have corrected the code. I face the same issue for both usernameTextEdit and passwordTextEdit. Guidance with XPath syntax or cssSelector would probably of some help.